# Bing search API results decreases with increase in web.offset(skip)value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, bing, bing-api

I am testing a query with Bing service explorer which returns the number of records to about 600k but while navigating to next page  the results keeps on decreasing and will eventually come to zero.

I am using both **Bing Search API** and **Bing Search Web Results only API** currently I am using free 5000 requests/month.

The example query which I am testing in Bing's service explorer is

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=%27xbox%27&Market=%27en-US%27&$skip=1300
```

I need to capture as many records as possible(>=10k) but with this it is limiting me to about 700 or 800 records .

what I am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted the question in bing search forum this is what they said hope it helps someone!

Search results are limited to the first 1,000 results. This means that the total of &top plus $skip can not be greater than 1,000.  The maximum value for &top is 100 for web, image, and video and 15 for news and the maximum value for $skip is 1000

Comment: Mansoor can you post a link to your question  in the bing search forum. I've only received 50 results in json format using top=100 and i'm wondering if that has become limited

Comment: I agree, $top=50 and $top=100 return 50 results, need to merge two calls of 50 using skip for the 2nd one.

Comment: @Mansoor Can we obtain the total number of search results for the query. example: I have searched for "chocolates" so I am interested in the total number of the documents this search query produces

Answer (score 2):

`$skip` mean that you are requesting result/ image after specified available bing data. For example if you specify `50` as `$skip` value, then it means it will ignore the first `50` data and start requesting result from data on `51` order.

Bing limiting to maximum `50` result per request. If you want to set the number of images you want to request, you can use `$top`. Its implementation is the same with `$skip`. Just put the number you want after `$top`. Example: `$top=33`.

What if you want to fetch images more than `50` per single **click**? You could multiply the request with php `for` loop to increase the `$skip` value and keep the `$top` value to the maximum allowed number to prevent skipping data per request.